# wpf - checkbox.isvisible is ture when one of the radio button is checked or no radio button checked

Tags: wpf, binding, radio-button, converters

I am new to Wpf
i have a group of 3 radio buttons 
for all the checkbox, it is not visible when none of the radio button is chekced or the third radio button on the group is checked.

I wonder if there is a way to achieved this?
I attempt built in booleanToVisibility but it does not work.
do i need to use something like multiple data trigger? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about MultiBinding. Your Xaml should look like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MultiBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="MultiBoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <RadioButton Name="rb1" Content="1"/>
        <RadioButton Name="rb2" Content="2"/>
        <RadioButton Name="rb3" Content="3"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Visible when 1 or 2 is checked.">
        <CheckBox.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBoolToVisibilityConverter}">
                <Binding Path="IsChecked"  ElementName="rb1" />
                <Binding Path="IsChecked"  ElementName="rb2" />
                <Binding Path="IsChecked"  ElementName="rb3" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </CheckBox.Visibility>
    </CheckBox>
</DockPanel>
```

The `MultiBoolToVisibilityConverter` in the converter should be defined in code behind, implementing `IMultiValueConverter`

```
public class MultiBoolToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool? firstRadioButtonIsChecked = values[0] as bool?;
        bool? secondRadioButtonIsChecked = values[1] as bool?;
        bool? thirdRadioButtonIsChecked = values[2] as bool?;

        //set your logic. this is just an example:
        if (firstRadioButtonIsChecked == true || secondRadioButtonIsChecked == true)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        return Visibility.Collapsed;

    } 

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

for further questions, you can see [this post on MultiBinding and IMultiValueConverter](https://blog.csainty.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html) among other google suggestions.